# Ember Utility class for accessing data across different places

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am new to Ember and want a Utility class in Ember which does the following, takes in rowItems and returns an object (finalMeta)

```
var myMeta1 = new Array();
var myMeta2 = new Array();

dojo.forEach(rowItems, dojo.hitch(this, function(rowItem){

    var metaData = {
            Id: rowItem.Id,
            version: rowItem.version
    };

    if(rowItem.tranMetaData.tpl){
        myMeta2.push(metaData);
    }else{
        myMeta1.push(metaData);
    }
}));

if(myMeta1.length == 0){
    myMeta1 = null;
}

if(myMeta2.length == 0){
    myMeta2 =  null;
}

var finalMeta = {
    "myMeta1": myMeta1,
    "myMeta2": myMeta2
};

return finalMeta;
```

Where/How do I write this Utility class, such that it can be accessed from a different place (say from a different route) ?

Just to add, I want to use the finalMeta in a child route (part of some workflow) as inputs/request params to some API.

In the child route, I would then make an AJAX call,

```
Ember.$.ajax({
                    url: someUrl,
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify({
                        'ids': idKeys,
'metaData': finalMeta
                    }),
    })
```

Comment: How are you using `finalMeta` once it is created?

Comment: I'll need this in other class (in other child route class) for passing as input to some API

Comment: This feels like it should go in some sort of service class for that API, and not in a standalone utility class.

Comment: Will multiple API's need to use this meta data?

Comment: Any example if you could give for service class ? Why do u think so ?

Comment: As of now, the intention is for single API, but yes in future it is possible that multiple APIs can use this metadata

Comment: Any example using Utility would be great as of now...i can probably decide later

Comment: Can you post an example API class or method so we can see how the meta data will be used?

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions come to mind. The first is probably the simplest to implement. The second might technically be more object oriented, but introduces another class with a very limited purpose.

The easy way: Include this as a method in your API service object:

```
function SomeApiService() {
}

SomeApiService.prototype = {
    constructor: SomeApiService,

    saveSomething: function(rows) {
        var finalMeta = this.getMetaData(rows);
        var idKeys = // create array of id keys

        Ember.$.ajax({
            url: someUrl,
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                'ids': idKeys,
                'metaData': finalMeta
            }),
        });
    },

    doSomethingElse: function(rows) {
        var finalMeta = this.getMetaData(rows);

        Ember.$.ajax({
            ...,
            data: JSON.stringify({
                metaData: finalMeta
            })
        });
    },

    getMetaData: function(rowItems) {
        var myMeta1 = [];
        var myMeta2 = [];

        dojo.forEach(rowItems, dojo.hitch(this, function(rowItem){

            var metaData = {
                    Id: rowItem.Id,
                    version: rowItem.version
            };

            if(rowItem.tranMetaData.tpl){
                myMeta2.push(metaData);
            }else{
                myMeta1.push(metaData);
            }
        }));

        if(myMeta1.length == 0){
            myMeta1 = null;
        }

        if(myMeta2.length == 0){
            myMeta2 =  null;
        }

        var finalMeta = {
            "myMeta1": myMeta1,
            "myMeta2": myMeta2
        };

        return finalMeta;
    }
};
```

Or, roll this into its own helper class and have the API service class use it:

Your API Service class becomes slimmer, but introduces a dependency. You can pass your own `metaHelper` in the constructor and provide a mock object for testing, but it could default to a new `MetaDataHelper` object.

```
function SomeApiService(metaHelper) {
    this.metaHelper = metaHelper || new MetaDataHelper();
}

SomeApiService.prototype = {
    constructor: SomeApiService,

    saveSomething: function(rows) {
        var finalMeta = this.metaHelper.getMetaData(rows);
        var idKeys = // create array of id keys

        Ember.$.ajax({
            url: someUrl,
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                'ids': idKeys,
                'metaData': finalMeta
            }),
        });
    },

    doSomethingElse: function(rows) {
        var finalMeta = this.metaHelper.getMetaData(rows);

        Ember.$.ajax({
            ...,
            data: JSON.stringify({
                metaData: finalMeta
            })
        });
    }
};
```

And the MetaDataHelper class doesn't contain much at this point, however you will have separated your concerns and made the meta data helper object testable by itself. This also allows you to write other API service classes that use the `MetaDataHelper` object to prevent the duplication of this logic.

```
function MetaDataHelper() {
}

MetaDataHelper.prototype.getMetaData = function(rowItems) {
        var myMeta1 = [];
        var myMeta2 = [];

        dojo.forEach(rowItems, dojo.hitch(this, function(rowItem){

            var metaData = {
                    Id: rowItem.Id,
                    version: rowItem.version
            };

            if(rowItem.tranMetaData.tpl){
                myMeta2.push(metaData);
            }else{
                myMeta1.push(metaData);
            }
        }));

        if(myMeta1.length == 0){
            myMeta1 = null;
        }

        if(myMeta2.length == 0){
            myMeta2 =  null;
        }

        var finalMeta = {
            "myMeta1": myMeta1,
            "myMeta2": myMeta2
        };

        return finalMeta;
};
```

Comment: Thx a lot for the detailed answer. Just a few things, I have used helpers, so understand that it will go in it's own folder (helpers)...But not sure about the service class..where that will go..Also assume to use them, we just need a simple import whereever we want to use (like child route or controller, etc)

Comment: Also to give more clarity on my requirement, initially I get a lit of rows from list api (which has a lot of row info/metadata) and after user can select some rows and start some workflow like 'Move items to status XYZ' (each of those rows have their own metadata from earlier api response now) and I want to make some new/child API calls picking some parts of the metadata (to be given as input to these new child API calls)
I call them as child since they are part of the workflow..but just to clarify it is some worfklow action initiated on selected rows from the initial list grid

Comment: so i assume the 2 approach that you have highlighted is the correct way for our requirement..Sorry, but am finding it hard to map things in a MVC framework like Ember coming from a normal Javascript

Comment: could you please suggest. Thx. Atleast if u could let me know where the API service would go...